# How to embed PowerShell into a Qt application as a widget?

Tags: windows, qt, powershell, embed

As the title points out, I'm looking for a way to use PowerShell in my own GUI application as a widget. The intention is to have PowerShell or an equivalent system shell working and accessible inside my application.

This stems from an idea for a hobby project, so a clarification whether this actually possible or if there is a better alternative for the same functionality would be nice.

Some searching via Google and Stackoverflow yielded unsatisfying results. There is this page,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee706563(v=vs.85).aspx, which could be the information I'm looking for, but it is structured rather cryptically to me as a hobbyist. Almost every other page in the search results seems to deal with other specifics of using PowerShell as a tool to embed, but not to be embedded.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Qt is a native framework, so to start you are going to need to embed .NET, in which the PSH will be hosted. Hosting .NET is likely to be easiest via COM (write a COM component .NET, then use that from your C++ code). Also rather than writing a full blown PSH host, consider just using a [RunSpaceInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/System.Management.Automation.RunspaceInvoke%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instance to execute PSH pipelines (linked to the easiest, but most limited approach, more sophistication is available: the `System.Management.Automation.Runspaces` namespace).

Comment: That clears the conceptual mess in my head, thanks for pointing the way.